# conditional changes behavior when converted to ternary operator?

Tags: java, algorithm, if-statement

I am writing a function that compares the number of vowels in the first half of a string and compares it with the second half, and returns a boolean based on if the number is equal.

Example:

```java
Input: "book"
Output: true
```

because `bo | ok`, `numVowels = 1`, one 'o' in both halves.

My code that works is here

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean halvesAreAlike(String s) {
        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'));                                
        int vowelCount = 0, length = (s.length()%2 == 0) ? s.length()/2 : s.length()/2+1;
        
        boolean pastHalf = false; 
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (i == length) pastHalf = true; 
            if (pastHalf && set.contains(s.charAt(i))) vowelCount--; 
            else if (!pastHalf && set.contains(s.charAt(i))) vowelCount++; 
        }
        return vowelCount == 0;                                                                    
    }
}
```

In the `if (i == length) pastHalf = true;` line, I am checking to see if I have hit the middle of the String. This is a simple boolean. I changed it to this ternary `pastHalf = (i == length) ? true : false;`  and the output was wrong for the test case `Ieai`. Does anyone know why? I believe that the statements are equivalent.

Comment: Did you step through the code in your IDE debugger to see what happens?  What did you find?

Comment: Also note that `pastHalf = (i == length) ? true : false;` is the same as `pastHalf = (i == length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (i == length) pastHalf = true;
```

is most definitely NOT the same as

```
pastHalf = (i == length) ? true : false
```

In the first case, `pastHalf` is changed only when `i` is exactly equal to `length`, so as you iterate beyond `length`, `pastHalf` *remains `true`*.

In the second, at each iteration `pastHalf` is reset, so `pastHalf` is true only when `i` is exactly equal to `length`.

Other improvements:

```
length = (s.length()+1) % 2;  // Think about this one carefully
```

and

```
if (set.contains(s.charAt(i))) 
    vowelCount += pastHalf ? -1 : +1;
```